# Attempting to implement quicksort using median-of-three and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

Tags: python, quicksort

Trying to implement quicksort using median-of-three as a refresher, I'm using the following algorithm: [image: here]

The only difference being that I am trying to use the middle of the three values (low, median and high) instead of the leftmost value as the pivot - from my understanding, this should only change a few lines of the code, but for some reason my algorithm doesn't seem to properly sort and I'm not entirely sure why? I've tried following it through and it doesn't work - but I don't quite know where and why it's wrong. I noticed my first problem is that somehow, my "0" in my array ends up in the completely wrong spot on the first partition pass, and I can't figure out why - unsure if that will help anyone pinpoint the problem, but I'm at my wit's end having stared at this all day and not getting anywhere.

```
def quicksort(arr, low, hi):
    def middle_of_three(arr, low, hi):
        mid = (low + hi) // 2
        if arr[low] > arr[mid]:
            arr[low], arr[mid] = arr[mid], arr[low]
        if arr[mid] > arr[hi]:
            arr[mid], arr[hi] = arr[hi], arr[mid]
        if arr[low] > arr[mid]:
            arr[low], arr[mid] = arr[mid], arr[low]
        return mid

    def partition(arr, low, hi):
        pivot = middle_of_three(arr, low, hi)  # get pivot index w/ median of three method
        left_wall = low
        for i in range(low + 1, hi):
            if arr[i] < arr[pivot]:
                arr[i], arr[left_wall] = arr[left_wall], arr[i]
                left_wall += 1
        arr[pivot], arr[left_wall] = arr[left_wall], arr[pivot]  # once you get to the end, swap pivot

        return left_wall

    if low < hi:
        pivot_loc = partition(arr, low, hi)
        quicksort(arr, low, pivot_loc)
        quicksort(arr, pivot_loc + 1, hi)
    print(sequence)


sequence = [2, 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 1, 0]
size = len(sequence) - 1
quicksort(sequence, 0, size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change middle_of_three to return the pivot value instead of the pivot index, and make similar changes to the rest of the code. The pivot element will usually get moved during the partition process, so using the pivot value will keep the code simpler.

I'm not familiar with the partition algorithm being used. Normally partition scans for a pair of elements where an element > pivot occurs before an element < pivot, and swaps them, repeating the process until reaching some scanning limit.  If using the middle element value as a pivot value, usually a variation of Hoare type partition scheme is used. Hoare scheme scans for elements > pivot from the left and for elements < pivot from the right, and stops when the indices for left and right scans meet somewhere in the middle of an array. The pivot index will be based on where the indices meet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

If you're still stuck, I can add a C / C++ example to my answer later.

Comment: see, the video I was watching found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hoixgm4-P4M used that same algorithm in the explanation, but the pseudocode didn't seem to reflect that, which had me confused.  I'll go ahead and make the changes and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: @TaiM - the video shows a partition scheme that initially swaps the pivot element to the end to move it out of the way, then swaps the pivot into place at the end. There's no need to do these swaps, as the pivot element will end up in it's sorted position due to swaps during a partition sequence. With the Hoare partition scheme, the pivot could end up in either the left or right sub-array, but it doesn't matter. Code can be added to isolate the pivot element from the two sub-arrays before doing recursion, but this won't help performance significantly.

Comment: So I finally got the problem solved! Following Hoare's algorithm (and a bit of googling to try and convert do whiles and "forever loop"s) I got it working like a charm - now I just have to get it to handle repeated integers as input but that's probably just an issue of an equals sign somewhere

Comment: @TaiM - just in case this is an issue. the two scans should use compares for elements < pivot and elements > pivot, not <= or >= , but you may already have the correct way.